# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail, google-workspace

I am trying to use smtp email functionality in my Laravel 6 Application.

## This is my .env file code :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=******@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Here it is the funny part :

1. It is working fine in my local host
2. It is also working in my server (without http)
3. It stopped working when I applied https in my server.

It gives me below error :

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "*********@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.14 
>    534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
>    534-5.7.14 Learn more at
>    534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g6sm37628450pja.2 - gsmtp
>    ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.14 
>    534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
>    534-5.7.14 Learn more at
>    534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g6sm37628450pja.2 - gsmtp
>    ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>    535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g6sm37628450pja.2 - gsmtp
>    ".

Note :

1. Allow less secure logged is enabled
2. This same email is not used in three application for the SMTP email functionality.

Comment: @DaImTo : this is the standard process of sending emails using SMTP in Laravel i am following. It is working fine in my localhost, server (http) but not working in https.

Answer (score 1):

the email is working in localhost, the less secure account account verification is correct

But you can't use your email in more than 3 projects, so you should stop using this email on other accounts.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your gmail password has the $ character, if so change it.
it worked for me

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.